# How to express in Legendre's polynomials?

Tags: legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

How do I express $cos(3\theta)$ and $sin^{2}(\theta)$ in Legendre's polynomials, knowing that $x=cos\theta$?

I know that $f(x)=\sum a_{n}P_{n}(x)$ and $P_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n}n!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(1-x^{2})^{n}$, but I don't know what to do with them

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can we do your homework, if you don't even copy the whole question? Could it be that you forgot to mention some connection between the variables $x$ and $\theta,$ something like "where $x=\cos\theta$" (though that is just a wild guess)? Your formula for $P_n$ is somewhat incomplete, too.

Comment: i forgot to say $x=cos\theta$

Comment: So you want to write Chebyshev polynomials as linear combinations of Legendre polynomials, is that correct?

Comment: the book I'm using doesn't have that. I'll look it up

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Legendre_polynomials_in_trigonometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions you are trying to match to Legendre polynomials of $\cos \theta$ are sinusoids, the easiest thing to do is usually to use trigonometric identities to re-express the function in terms of $\cos \theta$.  Then start from the highest order, match up the coefficients, and work your way down.

For example, suppose $f(\theta) = \cos(4 \theta) - \sin^2 (\theta)$.  We have
$$
\cos(4 \theta) = 2 \cos^2(2 \theta) - 1 = 2 (2 \cos (\theta) - 1)^2 - 1 = 8 \cos^4 \theta - 8 \cos^2 \theta + 1 = 8x^4 - 8x^2 + 1 
$$
and $\sin^2(\theta) = 1 - \cos^2 \theta = 1 - x^2.$  So
$$
f(x) = 8 x^4 - 7 x^2.
$$
The highest order of $x$ is 4, so the highest Legendre polynomial present is $P_4(x) = \frac{1}{8}(35 x^4 - 30 x^2 + 3).$  Subtract that out:
$$
f(x) - \frac{64}{35} P_4(x) = 8 x^4 - 7 x^2 - \frac{8}{35} (35 x^4 - 30 x^2 + 3) = - \frac{1}{7} x^2 - \frac{24}{35}
$$
Now we're down to $x^2$, so we can add in a multiple of $P_2(x)$:
$$
f(x) - \frac{64}{35} P_4(x) + \frac{2}{21} P_2(x) = - \frac{1}{7} x^2 - \frac{24}{35} + \frac{1}{21} (3 x^2 - 1) = - \frac{11}{35}
$$
And $P_0(x) = 1$, so
$$
f(x) - \frac{64}{35} P_4(x) + \frac{2}{21} P_2(x) + \frac{11}{15} P_0(x) = 0 \\ f(x) = \frac{64}{35} P_4(x) - \frac{2}{21} P_2(x) - \frac{11}{15} P_0(x).
$$